# An img that moves when shouldn't

Tags: html, css

So I have made a little website and I have found a problem. I have a two ul tags in a nav where I have put a couple of li tags in and then some ul tags in some of those li tags I have also put an img in one of those li tags in another li. When I then apply some animations the img moves along with the other tabs... Here are some pictures;

[When nothing is touched with the mouse. Everything looks fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RK9nt.png)

[When I'm hovering over the lock (the img I was walking about) it is moving to the right and showing a logout button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejPIe.png)

[But when I'm dragging this down the lock img is following down.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LSH6c.png)

[Here too](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQlus.png)

And here is the code of the whole nav bar:

```css
body{
  margin-left: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: arial;
  background-color: #E9EBEE !important;
}

nav {
    margin-top: -10px;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: #2A3943;
    padding: 5px;
    box-shadow: 2.5px 2.5px 2.5px #888888;
    border-radius: 4px;
    z-index: 1;
}

nav h1 {
    color: white;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

nav ul {
    margin-left: 27%;
    list-style: none;
    margin-top: -55px;
}

nav ul li {
    border-radius: 2px;
    float: left;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-left: 5px;
    display: inline;
    padding: 21.5px;
    background-color: #1AB188;
    transition: all .5s ease;
    box-shadow: 2.5px 2.5px 2.5px #0d1215;
}

nav ul li:hover {
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #0d1215;
}

nav ul li#pleb {
    height: 19px;
}

nav ul li#pleb ul {
    margin-top: -80px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all .5s ease;
}

nav ul li#pleb:hover ul {
    opacity: 1;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

nav ul li#pleb:hover {
    height: 290px;
}

nav ul li:hover {
    background-color: #179E79;
}

nav ul li ul.dropdwn li {
    display: none;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: -90px;
}

nav ul li:hover ul.dropdwn li {
    display: block;
}

nav ul li ul li:hover {
    background-color: #2A3943;
}

nav ul li a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul li#fort {
    height: 19px;
}

nav ul li#fort:hover {
    height: 400px;
}

nav ul li#fort ul {
    margin-left: -50px;
    margin-top: -300px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all .5s ease;
}

nav ul li#fort:hover ul {
    margin-top: 20px;
    opacity: 1;
}

nav ul li#fort ul.drpdown li {
    display: none;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

nav ul li#fort:hover ul.drpdown li {
    display: block;
}

nav .login ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin-top: 0px;
    border-color: none;
}

nav .login ul li {
    background-color: rgba(38, 181, 150, 0);
    box-shadow: none;
    margin-top: -80px;
    margin-left: 770px;
    transition: all .5s ease;
}

nav .login ul li:hover {
    transform: translateX(-100px);
    
}

nav .login ul li img {
    width: 40px;
}

nav .login ul li img:hover {
    transform: none;
}

nav .login ul li ul li {
    display: none;
    margin-left: -30px;
    margin-top: -60px;
    transition: none;
    background-color: rgba(119, 221, 110, 0);
}

nav .login ul li ul li#signup {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top: -60px;
}

nav .login ul li ul li#logout {
    margin-left: -10px;
}

nav .login ul li:hover ul li {
    display: block;
    transform: none;
}

nav .login ul li ul li button {
    border: none;
    padding: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: rgba(164, 19, 34, 0);
    color: #fff;
    transition: all .5s ease;
}

nav .login ul li ul li button:hover {
    background-color: #1AB188;
    padding: 10px;
}

nav .login ul li ul li#signup button {
    width: 80px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <h1>MemeStagram</h1>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
    <li id="pleb"><a href="memes.php">Memes</a>
      <ul class="dropdwn">
        <li><a href="most-popular.php">Most Popular</a></li><br>
        <li><a href="newest.php">Newest</a></li><br>
        <li><a href="most-viewed.php">Most Viewed</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="about.php">About Us</a></li>
    <li id="fort"><a href="contact.php">Contact</a>
      <ul class="drpdown">
          <li><a href="bebin.php">Bebin</a></li><br>
          <li><a href="balbin.php">Balbin</a></li><br>
          <li><a href="bohan.php">Bohan</a></li><br>
          <li><a href="barcus.php">Barcus</a></li><br>
          <li><a href="bonis.php">Bonis</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="settings.php">Settings</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="login">
    <ul>
      <li><img src="img/unlock.png">
        <ul>
          <li id="logout">
            <a href="logout.php"><button type="submit">Logout</button></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

I Would be really thankful for help with this problem. And I have tried to set position: absolute; and position: fixed; but it didn't give me any positive result...

//Kevin

Comment: Overall this is horribly formatted code and styling. I will rebuild your navigation for you. Give me some time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find below a complete rewrite of your code as it was all over the place and was not consistent with standards. Please read over the below code and look where you went wrong to learn more about css.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    * {font-family: arial;}
    header {background-color: #2A3943;padding: 10px 40px;box-shadow: 2.5px 2.5px 2.5px #888888;border-radius: 4px;}
    header nav h1 {display: inline-block;color: white;}
    header nav {display: block;}
    header nav ul {list-style: none; padding: 0px;display: block;}
    header nav ul li {position:relative;display: inline-block;border-radius: 2px;cursor: pointer;padding: 22px;background-color: #1AB188;box-shadow: 2.5px 2.5px 2.5px #0d1215;margin:0px 5px;text-align: center;}
    header nav ul li:hover > ul {visibility: visible;transform: translateY(0%);transition-delay: 0s, 0s, 0.3s;opacity: 1}
    header nav ul li > ul {background-color:#1AB188;top:60px;visibility: hidden;position: absolute;width: 100%;transform: translateY(-2em);transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s, visibility 0s linear 0.3s, z-index 0s linear 0.01s;left:0px;opacity: 0;}
    header nav ul li a {text-decoration: none;color: white;display: block;}
    header nav ul li a:hover {color: #333;}
    header nav ul li:last-child {float: right;margin-right: 0px;padding: 20px 0px; background: none;box-shadow: none;}
    header nav ul li:first-child {border-radius: none;padding: 0px;background-color:transparent;box-shadow: none;margin-right: 40px;}
    header nav ul li:nth-child(2) {margin-left: 0px;}
    header nav ul li:last-child > * {display: inline-block;vertical-align: middle;}
    header nav ul li:last-child img {margin-right: 20px;width: 40px;}
    header nav ul li:last-child:hover a button {visibility: visible;transform: translateX(0%);transition-delay: 0s, 0s, 0.3s;opacity: 1}
    header nav ul li a button {padding: 5px;cursor: pointer;background-color: rgba(164, 19, 34, 0);color: #fff;visibility: hidden;transform: translateX(2em);transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s, visibility 0s linear 0.3s;opacity: 0;}
    header nav ul li > ul li {box-shadow: none;background: none;display: block;border-radius: 0px;margin:0px;padding: 21px !important}
    header nav ul li > ul li:last-child {float: none;}
    header nav ul li > ul li:first-child {margin: 0px;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
<header>
    <nav>

        <ul>
            <li><h1>MemeStagram</h1></li>
            <li><a href="index.php" title="Home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="memes.php" title="Memes">Memes</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="most-popular.php" title="Most Popular">Most Popular</a></li><br>
                    <li><a href="newest.php" title="Newest">Newest</a></li>
                    <li><a href="most-viewed.php" title="Most Viewed">Most Viewed</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="about.php" title="About Us">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.php" target="Contact">Contact</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="bebin.php" title="Bebin">Bebin</a></li>
                    <li><a href="balbin.php" title="Balbin">Balbin</a></li>
                    <li><a href="bohan.php" title="Bohan">Bohan</a></li>
                    <li><a href="barcus.php" title="Barcus">Barcus</a></li>
                    <li><a href="bonis.php" title="Bonis">Bonis</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="settings.php" title="Settings">Settings</a></li>
            <li class="login"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f4/Simpleicons_Interface_unlocked-padlock.svg/1024px-Simpleicons_Interface_unlocked-padlock.svg.png" alt="Login/Logout"><a href="logout.php" title="logout"><button type="submit">Logout</button></a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

As you seem pretty new to css I will explain the of selectors used:

```
> This selector means "directly inside" so when I put li > ul it means target the UL directly inside an li
* this selector means everything, where I have set everything to have font-famly:arial.
:hover this selector means on hover of the element its attached to, do something
:last-child this selector means the last child of the attached element
:first-child this selector means the first child the attached element
```

Heres a working codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MrPBEW

Comment: Thanks a lot, man! Ye as you say I'm pretty new to everything in the web developer world :D Thanks for rebuilding my entire header! I will definetly take your tips to my heart and think more of what I do in CSS in the future!

Comment: Could you mark this reply as the answer :) This is so people can see that you got the right help and it rewards me for my efforts. Glad I could help!